# Connecting multiple checkboxes through a loop using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to use a loop to create multiple Checkboxes. I'd like to be able to convert this grid of boxes to make a numpy array. The code manually creates a 5x5 matrix of checkboxes, corresponding to the same point in the numpy array. When this code is run and boxes are checked by the user, the numpy array *alaways* prints as such:

```
[[False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True]]
```

I really don't know what's wrong.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QCheckBox)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid =np.zeros([5,5], dtype=bool)
        self.x_pos, self.y_pos = 0, 0
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
                self.x_pos, self.y_pos = i, j
                btn = QCheckBox(self)
                btn.move(50+17*i, 50+17*j)
                # btn.toggle()
                btn.stateChanged.connect(self.click)



        done = QPushButton('Done', self)
        done.clicked.connect(self._print)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

    def click(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.grid[self.x_pos][self.y_pos] = True
        else:
            self.grid[self.x_pos][self.y_pos] = False


    def _print(self):
        print(self.grid)
```

Comment: `self.x_pos` and `self.y_pos` is changed while `initUI()` is running, but after that you don't change the variable. Therefore, those 2 variables stay `[5,5]` and only the element in that position changes.  You should assign the number that can track down the position of actual checkbox to those 2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem causing only your last element in array to change is you not assigning position after creating checkbuttons. Therefore it stays `5,5`

One way to solve this problem is to assign checkbuttons into QGridLayout and renew every grid for every inputs. The code will be as follows :

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout`

Under `def __init__(self):`

```
self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
self.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
```

under `def initUI(self)`:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        btn = QCheckBox()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(btn,i,j)
        btn.stateChanged.connect(self.click)
```

under `def click(self,state)`:

```
if state == Qt.Checked :
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            item = self.grid_layout.itemAtPosition(i,j)
            widget = item.widget()
            self.grid[i][j] = widget.isChecked()
else :
    pass
```

Comment: I had originally thought of using a grid object, but it never returns the correct layout. I need an actual grid of checkboxes with very little space in between. Also, running your code throws the error: `AttributeError: 'QWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'Widget'`

Comment: theres' typo in the widget = item.Widget(). this should be widget = item.widget().

Comment: Still the same error. In any case, it still doesn't provide the output I'm looking for. I need a matrix of checkboxes. I tried using the built-in grid object, but it produced a grid with huge spaces inbetween the boxes, nothing seemed to change it, either.

Edit: error in question `NoneType' object has no attribute 'widget'`

Comment: That's quite confusing because I am currently running same code as I've uploaded... Can you specify how the matrix is not showing up? Is it not in 5*5 matrix or not even showing?

Comment: The code will execute, but produce a window with 10 checkboxes all aligned vertically. If I click one, it automatically throws the error above without even clicking "done".

Comment: Oops, there's another typo there... `self.grid_layout.addWidget(btn)` should be `self.grid_layout.addWidget(btn,i,j)` I'm pretty sure that this one has caused the `Nonetype error` you met before...

Comment: Oh, that works now. The grid is still far too spaced out though. This won't be usable unless there's a way to modify it. I tried to add something like `self.grid_layout.horizontalSpacing = 1` and `self.grid_layout.setHorizontalSpacing(1)` under `__init__()`, but it never seems to have an effect.